# How dotenv Package Work With pg.Pool in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, dotenv

I've read some code that uses the dotenv package to create configurations.
When I read a file that contains PostgreSQL code for Pool, the code looks like this:

```
const pg = require('pg')
const { Pool } = pg

// This pool was created without completing the pool connection configuration. 
const pool = new Pool()
```

However, I see that this pool configuration is written in the.env file.

```
#POOL CONFIGURATIONS
PGUSER=username
PGPASSWORD=password
PGHOST=localhost
PGDATABASE=databasename
PGPORT=5432
```

and .env file is called once in main file :

```
// main file
require('dotenv').config() 
const express = require('express')

// below is the server
```

Why is a pool created without passing any configuration objects as arguments?
How does it work in the background?
I still can't figure this out clearly.

I've tried searching for this behavior, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

that sets everything in your `.env` file to be on `process.env.*`.

For example, you say `PGUSER=username`, so now `process.env.PGUSER === "username"`

`pg.Pool` seems to go with those environment variables by default